# How to graph plots that only have enough data?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, ggplot2

I am working with a large dataset of wild animal weights and sizes that I divide up into smaller sections by date (season 1, season 2, etc).  I wrote a function to create graphs in ggplot2 for each individual animal, but some animals were caught so infrequently that their data is essentially meaningless.

How can I alter this function to only graph animals that appear within the given subset more than 3 or 4 times?

Here's the function as I have it:

```
individual_graph <- function(animal_number){
  a_plot <- ggplot(data=animal_number, aes(x=Date, y=Weight)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw() +
    ggtitle(animal_number$Number)+
    NULL

  return(a_plot)
}
```

And here is the for loop that I use for generating the graphs:

```
  graph_list <- list(NULL)
for(animal_id in (unique(season_1$Number))){
  a <- individual_graph(season_1[Number==animal_id])
  graph_list <- c(graph_list, list(a))
}

plot_list
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe there is a better way than a loop, but's hard to find without having any kind of data. Could you put a useful example of them?

Comment: `filter` from `dplyr` should get you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table(animal_number)
```

tells you which animal has been seen how many times (sorted by animal_number).

```
seen3times<-sort(unique(animal_number))[tabulate(factor(animal_number))>3]
```

will give you the unique animal numbers for all that have been seen at least 3 times, then using

```
data[which(animal_number==seen3times)]
```

should filter your data accordingly